# Problema con validación 'confirmed' de contraseña en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validación

Hola tengo un problema en la validación de la contraseña al crear un usuario. Estoy usando la regla 'confirmed' de laravel y me tira el mensaje "The password confirmation does not match." Tengo 2 input obviamente el 'password' y el 'confirma password' pero no entiendo porque me da ese mensaje. Help!!

Controlador

```
$data = request()->validate([
      'nombre' => 'required',
      'username' => 'required|unique:users,userName',
      'email' => 'required|unique:users,email|email',
      'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);
```

Vista

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese password">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta el atributo name en el input de confirmación.

```
<input type="password" **name="password_confirmation"**
 class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la documentacion de laravel...

> The field under validation must have a matching field of
>   foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is
>   password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in
>   the input.

por tanto, el nombre del campo de confirmación para el password deberia terminar en **_confirmation**.